# Using Branch.io generated link with Facebook share dialog

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, branch.io

I went through Branch.io's documentation a lot over the past few days and I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. I got the generated link to work properly by setting up the `BranchUniversalObject` as follows:

```
let branchUniversalObject: BranchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: "ios_share_user")
branchUniversalObject.title = "My Title"
branchUniversalObject.contentDescription = "My Description"
branchUniversalObject.imageUrl = "www.example.com/image.jpg"
branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("id", value: self.userId)
branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("type", value: self.userType)

let linkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
linkProperties.channel = "Facebook"
linkProperties.feature = "Share"

branchUniversalObject.getShortUrl(with: linkProperties, andCallback: { (shareURL, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    // using shareURL here
})
```

The generated URL works perfectly fine, but only when launched from Notes or Messages apps. Safari always redirects me to the AppStore and so does the Facebook app when I try sharing the URL like this:

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentTitle = "My Title"
content.contentURL = shareURL     // generated above
content.contentDescription = "My Description"
content.imageURL = "www.example.com/image.jpg"

let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.fromViewController = self
dialog.delegate = self
dialog.shareContent = content

if dialog.canShow() {
    dialog.show()
}
```

That shows up the dialog and shares the content as intended, but the link always redirects me to the AppStore just like in Safari.

Here's a screenshot of the Dashboard:
[image]

I also have `applinks:myLinkDomain.app.link` and `applinks:myLinkDomain-alternate.app.link` in the Associated Domains, `branch_app_domain` = `myLinkDomain.app.link` along with `branch_key` = `["live": "key_live_myKey"]` in `Info.plist`, and AppDelegate is properly set.

What am I missing to get the app to open from Safari and Facebook instead of getting redirected to the AppStore?

I'm deploying the app for iOS 9.3+

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [link](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links) and it shows that the problem isn't with Branch.io SDK's setup by any means, but a limitation imposed by Apple. The only workaround is using Branch's Deepviews, which unfortunately I can't use in my case.

Hope Branch.io figure out a way around that! ...And possibly update their documentation to clearly state that some app browsers are not supported

Comment: Alex from Branch here: thanks for the note (and the thorough, top-notch question details). You're running into Universal Link issues caused by both Apple and Facebook — Branch helps work around some of these limitations, but unfortunately can't fix _all_ of them. We can manually enable Deepviews only for Facebook links, if that is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @AlexBauer! :) 
That's completely understandable. Thanks for the tip as well! I didn't know about enabling Deepviews for Facebook links only... I'll look more into it and post an update to my answer if I come across any interesting/helpful findings!

Comment: You're welcome! It's a setting that must be manually enabled by our Integrations team, so [let us know](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) if you're interested